# Rayleigh Distribution - Density, Expected Value Question

Tags: probability, statistics

This is a question on a review sheet I'm studying for. I know how to integrate by parts, but I don't know how to pull the probability function of the normal distribution. It's needed to complete this problem, I just don't know how to get it.

Question is:

Rayleigh distribution has density:
$$
f(y) = \frac y{a^2} \cdot e^\left(-\frac{y^2}{2a^2}\right) 
$$
for $y \ge 0$, where $a > 0$ is a constant.

Find $\def\E{\mathbf E}\E(Y)$.

And yes, I know that $\E(Y) = \int_0^\infty yf(y)\, dy$, I just don't know where the probability function of the normal distribution comes into play while integrating this.

Answer (score 2):

Note that a $\def\E{\mathbf E}N(\mu, \sigma^2)$-distributed variable has the density
$$ g_{\mu,\sigma^2}(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \cdot \exp \left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) $$
Now, when calculating $\E[Y]$, we have
\begin{align*}
  \E[Y] &= \int_0^\infty \frac{y^2}{a^2}\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2a^2}\right)\, dy\\
   &= \frac 12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{y^2}{a^2}\exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2a^2}\right)\, dy\\
  &= \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2|a|} \int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 g_{0,a^2}(y)\, dy 
\end{align*}
The latter is $\sqrt{2\pi}/2|a|$ times the variance of a $N(0,a^2)$-distributed variable, that is $\sqrt{\frac\pi 2}|a|$.

Comment: So in this case e^(...) / 2 is replaced by the normal distribution? Will this happen to all density functions with similar components?